# "this" reference escaping during construction?

Tags: java, constructor

If I do the following,

```
final class FooButton extends JButton{
    FooButton(){
        super("Foo");
        addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                // do stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```

am I letting the `this` reference implicitly escape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because in the anonymous inner class you could access it like this:

```
final class FooButton extends JButton {
    Foo() {
        super("Foo");
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FooButton button = FooButton.this;
                // ... do something with the button
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code of the anonymous `ActionListener` could in principle be called and use the `FooButton` before the `FooButton` object is fully initialized.

Comment: what is the official name of " FooButton.this" kind of construct ?

Comment: @Geek, [Qualified this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the this reference escapes to the listener. Since this listener is not really an external class, I don't see any problem with it, though.

Here's where you could see that this escapes:

```
final class FooButton extends JButton{
    Foo(){
        super("Foo");
        addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            private buttonText = FooButton.this.getText(); // empty string

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                // do stuff
            }
        });
        this.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the anonymous inner class of `ActionListener` has a reference to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `this` of the enclosing class is implicitly in an non-static anonymous class.