# List of objects that implements interface

Tags: java, interface, kotlin

With

```
interface Anint {
    fun doStuff()
}

class AClass : Anint {
    override fun doStuff() = print("hello")
}

class AnintManager {
    //val l = listOf<Anint>
    fun manage() { //for each Anint, doStuff() }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = AClass()
    val b = AClass()
    AnintManager().manage()
}
```

How can I do so that every time I instanciate a new object that implement "Anint", that object gets added to list in the "AnintManager"? It'll be cool if the code for achieving this is placed in the interface

Comment: You would need an `Anint`-FactoryMethod for that, which creates the implementation and then registers that impl to the `Manager`.

Comment: you can make it a static list somewhere, and call a static method that adds elements to it from within the constructor

Comment: @Stultuske let `this` escape from constructor is said to be bad design. And can break the whole programm

Comment: @Stultuske have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8446036/5515060)

Comment: @Lino So I should do a method like "createAnint(anintInstance: Anint)" that returns an object implementing Anint while adding it to the list ? If so, where should it be ? In the "AnintManager" class or elsewhere?

Comment: That's what you have to decide, you could make a static method in `AnintManager` which returns `AClass` and registers that instance

Comment: @Lino seems good to me, thanks ;)